# How to use variables in a loop - Databricks

Tags: loops, variables, databricks

I have the following code in SAS EG and I need to replicate it in Databricks. I'm still very new to cloud, and spark.  Not sure how to use variables in this context.

%macro emp_hrchy;
proc sql;
create table level_0 as
select
[some employee information],
'L0' as HIERARCHY_LEVEL,
[some more employee information]
from
[source table] a
left join [source table] l1 on [join condition]
left join [source table] l2 on [join condition]
left join [source table] l3 on [join condition]
where
[some conditions];
quit;

```
data emp_hierarchy_tmp; set level_0; run;

%macro hierarchy;
%do k=1 %to 9;
%let j = %sysfunc(sum(&k. -1));
%put &j.;

proc sql;
create table level_&k. as
select 
    [some employee information],
    'L&k.' as HIERARCHY_LEVEL,
    [some more employee information]
from 
    [source table] a
    left join [source table] l1 on [join condition]
    left join [source table] l2 on [join condition]
    left join [source table] l3 on [join condition]
    join level_&j. b on [join condition];
quit;
proc append data=level_&k. base=emp_hierarchy_tmp; run;
%end;
%mend hierarchy;
%hierarchy;

%macro loop;
%do k=9 %to 1 %by -1;
    %let j = %sysfunc(sum(&k. -1));
    %let z = %sysfunc(sum(&k.-2));

    %if &k. = 9 %then %do;
    proc sql;
    create table emp_hierarchy as
    select 
        a.*,
        b.full_name as L&j._NAME,
        b.business_title as L&j._TITLE,
        b.supervisor_id as fk_&z.
    from 
        emp_hierarchy_tmp a
        left join level_&j. b on [join condition] and b.hierarchy_level = "L&j.";
    quit;
    %end;

    %else %if &k. >1 %then %do;
    proc sql;
    create table emp_hierarchy as
    select 
        a.*,
        b.full_name as L&j._NAME,
        b.business_title as L&j._TITLE,
        b.supervisor_id as fk_&z.
    from 
        emp_hierarchy a
        left join level_&j. b on [join condition] and b.hierarchy_level = "L&j.";
    quit;
    %end;

    %else %do;
    proc sql;
    create table emp_hierarchy as
    select 
        a.*,
        b.full_name as L&j._NAME,
        b.business_title as L&j._TITLE
    from 
        emp_hierarchy a
        left join level_&j. b on [join condition] and b.hierarchy_level = "L&j.";
    quit;
    %end;
%end;

data emp_hierarchy; set emp_hierarchy; drop fk_1-fk_7; run;

%mend loop;
%loop;
```

%mend emp_hrchy;

I tried this but it fails miserably:
%python
for k in range(1, 10):
var = spark.sql(f""" select {k}-1 as j """)

```
    #Storein the values into variables.
    j = var.collect()[0][0]

    df= spark.sql(f"""
    select 
        [some employee information],
        'L&k.' as HIERARCHY_LEVEL,
        [some more employee information]
    from 
        [source table] a
        left join [source table] l1 on [join condition]
        left join [source table] l2 on [join condition]
        left join [source table] l3 on [join condition]
        join level_{j} b on [join condition]
    """)
```

df.createOrReplaceTempView("level_{y}")

I tried ALL the different recommendations from "the Assistant", but every code fix caused another error. I must have tried 4 or 5 different solutions offered by the assistant.